# Belkin kvm switch ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-switch

I have installed a Belkin kvm dual head switch, model F1DN104W-3, but I have only one screen working. The second screen has no signal. I tried also to switch the cables with the same result. Do I have to install some additional drivers on Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you contacted Belkin support?  They are usually very responsive.

Comment: yes I have, but I have to wait 48h for a response....